# Partition SQL Server tables based on column not in the primary key?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
create table test_partitions 
(
    pk_id int not null,
    col1 nvarchar(20),
    col2 nvarchar(100),

    constraint pk_test_partitions primary key (pk_id, col1)
);
```

I want to partition this table to improve query performance so that I don't have to look through the whole table every time I need something. So I added a calculated column:

```
create table test_partitions 
(
    pk_id int not null,
    partition_id as pk_id % 10 persisted not null,
    col1 nvarchar(20),
    col2 nvarchar(100),

    constraint pk_test_partitions primary key (pk_id, col1)
);
```

So ever time I do `select * from test_partitions where pk_id = 123` I want SQL Server to look in only 1/10th of the entire table. I don't want to add `partition_id` column to the primary key because it will never be part of the where clause. How do I partition my table on `partition_id`?

Comment: You don't need to partition it. You just need to add a non clustered index. To see if indexes / partitions are being used, check the query plan.

Comment: you don't need an extra non clustered index or any partitioning, if your primary key has leading column `pk_id` (as shown) the clustered index on that will allow your predicate to be seeked fine.

Comment: @MartinSmith you're right I didn't even realise the OP thought that a clustered index wouldn't help... so I reiterate: check the query plan before making assumptions!

Answer (score 0):

Just right now i did test and found a solution

```
SELECT TOP ((SELECT COUNT(*) [TABLE_NAME])/10)     
* FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

it returns 1/10th of your records

Answer (score 0):

To improve your query performance you can apply pagination. That is you can use **fetch next** query to achieve your output.
Please go through [this](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/order-by-offset-fetch) for more details.

```
  SELECT column-names FROM table-name
  ORDER BY column-names 
  OFFSET n ROWS
  FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY
```